# Creating Views using both XML and code - elements not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I am making a simple soundboard app - buttons should appear in two columns, pressing a button plays a sound. I made it and had all the buttons defined using XML and it worked fine, but since the app was already attaching a listener to play a sound using a loop, I decided to define the buttons using only code.

So the code has no errors and the app launches but no buttons appear. There is a similar problem here: [Content not showing in dynamically created android TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154800/content-not-showing-in-dynamically-created-android-tablelayout) although if I understand it correctly, the proposed solution (ensure Im using `TableLayout.LayoutParams`) is already applied here.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_table2);

    int[] sounds = { ... };

    String[] labels = { ... };

    declareButtons(sounds, labels);
}

private void declareButtons(int[] sounds, String[] labels)
{
    TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.tblMain);
    TableRow row = null;
    Button cell;

    for (int i=0; i<sounds.length; i++)
    {
        cell = new Button(this);
        cell.setText(labels[i]);
        cell.setOnClickListener(this.getStartListener(sounds[i]));

        cell.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.soundbutton));
        cell.setTextColor(color.white);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams cellParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (float) 1);
        cellParams.leftMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        cellParams.topMargin = cellParams.leftMargin;

        if (i%2==0) // left column
        {
            row = new TableRow(this);
            cell.setLayoutParams(cellParams);
            row.addView(cell);
        }
        else // right column
        {
            cellParams.rightMargin = cellParams.leftMargin;
            cell.setLayoutParams(cellParams);
            row.addView(cell);
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            tbl.addView(row);
        }
    }

    if (sounds.length%2 > 0) // handle uneven amount of buttons
        tbl.addView(row);
}
```

And here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/leonbg2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblMain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how table rows were defined previously, which worked fine:

```
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonaw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/soundbutton"
                android:text="A what?"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttona"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/soundbutton"
                android:text="Argh!"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: I think you are creating same Button **cell** always in the loop, shouldn't it be different for each iteration like an array of buttons or whatever? And where are you setting your view to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to fix it myself by getting rid of `TableLayout` and going for a bunch of `LinearLayout`s (one for each row). The code is more or less the same with the addition of `row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);` before `cell.setLayoutParams(cellParams);` in the left column part of the if statement. The moral of the story is; if you think you need to use TableLayout, you probably dont. Peace.