# Adding a Table Layout within a Linear Layout Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I basically want something like:

```
  TextView
  Button
  Button
  .
  .
  .
  TextView   TextView
  SeekBar
  Button
```

I have to do this programmatically.
Now, I have everything working except for the fact that the TextViews above the SeekBar are not showing.

The relevant code that is doing this work is

```
//Setting the linear layout
    ll =  new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());                //a linear layout encompasses all the other elements
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);   //orientation has to be vertical
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));     //the layout occupies the complete screen

    //Set the TextView for the Question
    tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    //sets the dimensions of the textView
    ll.addView(tv1);                            //add the TextView to the LinearLayout

    //Set the buttons (?)
    b = new Button [MAX_OPTIONS];               
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_OPTIONS;i++){
        b[i] = new Button(getApplicationContext());     //set the context for each button
        b[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll.addView(b[i]);
    }

    //Set the Table Layout
    tl = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    tl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tl.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
    tl.setColumnStretchable(1, true);

    //Set the Table Row
    tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.setPadding(dipConvert(5), dipConvert(5), dipConvert(5), dipConvert(5));

    //Set the two TextViews
    tv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);               //set the gravity of this TextView to left
    tv3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv3.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    tv3.setPadding(0, 0, dipConvert(15), 0);    //set the padding for this to be displayed(the number 15 was emperically determined)

    //Add the Textview to table row
    tr.addView(tv2);        tr.addView(tv3);

    //Add the TableRow to the Table Layout
    tl.addView(tr);

    //Add the TableLayout to the LinearLayout
    ll.addView(tl);

    //Set the Seekbar
    sb1 = new SeekBar(getApplicationContext());
    sb1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    sb1.setMax(100);
    sb1.setMinimumWidth(250);
    ll.addView(sb1);

    //Set the Seekbar Button
    sb1_b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    sb1_b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ll.addView(sb1_b);
            setContentView(ll);
```

I cannot figure out what is going on. The display I get is something like

```
   TextView
   Button
   Button
   .
   .
   .

   SeekBar
   Button
```

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to need TableRow.layout param in the child elements of the tableRow elements. This has been explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10156822/1322460). Please refer it and correct it. It is a very simple hiccup, which can be easily ignored.

Your textview should be

```
tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and similarly for tv3 as well.

Comment: worked perfectly for me! thanks! could you explain WHY do we need to do this? I mean to me it seems like the thing I was doing was fine (which obviously was not). This has kind of confused me.

Comment: Great. congrats. This is because android differentiates the layout parameters of a table and a table's row. So the proper parameter has to be passed for the Android OS to understand that a row has to be added.